# Using native module versions with Aurelia.io application

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, aurelia

Our application is built using Aurelia.io and needs to run on Internet Explorer 11. When we build the Aurelia libraries bundle, Webpack is grabbing the versions in the es2015 folders for the various libraries. We need Webpack to use the native-modules versions instead. How do I tell npm or Webpack which version to use?

Comment: I think this has already been fixed. If you grab the latest version of all plugins and rebuild, it will work just fine with IE11